# MSWORD VBA close document on save

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I am trying to get a document to close when saved, using VBA.

I have searched for this extensively but mostly it comes up with people trying to not turn off saving when closing a document. 
What I have so far is the following (I removed the unrelated code).

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveDocument.Close
End Sub
```

This causes word to crash and the document not to save, possibly because it is in the wrong procedure?
Replacing `ActiveDocument.close` with `App.Quit` works but this closes all open documents(this is not the desired behaviour).

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [so] duplicate: [Trigger MS Word macro after save event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3636625)

Comment: That is not a duplicate. I want to close the document after the save not run  any other code.

Comment: It is, because it tells you what to do to solve the problem, **complete with example code**.

Comment: I am fairly sure I tried that yesterday, I will try it again now. an post back

Comment: That is just a save macro, it does nothing when words "save as"  is called, or when save is pressed. The code there has to be called. Many thanks for trying to be helpful though

Comment: Wrong. See [Modifying a Word Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211946%28v=office.11%29.aspx) - You can add additional instructions or remove the existing `ActiveDocument.Save` instruction. Now every time the `FileSave` command runs, your `FileSave` macro runs instead of the word command. To restore the original `FileSave` functionality, you need to rename or delete your `FileSave` macro.

Comment: See the above and add `ActiveDocument.Close` after `ActiveDocument.Save`

Comment: Many thanks David that was what I was looking for. The 'FileSave' command.

Comment: Great. It will be an answer in a minute ;)

Comment: I would just like to say that the FileSaveAs one does nothing for me

Comment: Strange - `FileSaveAs`  should wok in the same way as `FileSave`

Comment: Sub FileSaveAs()
Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show
ActiveDocument.Close
End Sub

Comment: the above comment is what I have but save as just works normally

Comment: Follow the instructions exactly as in my answer, replacing `FileSave` with `FileSaveAs`

Comment: Just thought I would Post back, FileSaveAs only works for "SaveAs" on the Ribbon and will not be entered into the Document templates (just Normal,dot)  and not for the back stage. I don't suppose you know a way to modify the back stage with out modifying .xml?

Answer (score 2):

#### I am trying to get a document to close when saved, using VBA.

You can override (modify) existing word commands.

In this case you need to modify `FileSave` and add `ActiveDocument.Close` after `ActiveDocument.Save` in the code below.

---

#### Modifying a Word Command

> This example takes you through the steps needed to modify the
>   `FileSave` command.
>
> 1. On the Tools menu, point to Macro, and then click Macros.
> 2. In the Macros in box, select Word commands.
> 3. In the Macro name box, select FileSave.
> 4. In the Macros in box, select a template or document location to store the macro.
>
>    For example, select `Normal.dot` (Global Template) to create a global
>      macro (the `FileSave` command will be modified for all documents).
> 5. Click the Create button.
>
> The FileSave macro appears as shown below.

```
Sub FileSave()
'
' FileSave Macro
' Saves the active document or template
'
    ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub
```

> You can add additional instructions or remove the existing
>   `ActiveDocument.Save` instruction.
>
> Now every time the `FileSave` command runs, your `FileSave` macro runs
>   instead of the word command. To restore the original `FileSave`
>   functionality, you need to rename or delete your `FileSave` macro.

Source [Modifying a Word Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211946%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: The documentation that is basically a unicorn to me. Excellent answer! +1